# Calculate total when the value is on two different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I wan't to be able to calculate the value of two function then output the result in an ul list.

the function standardRoom() and quadRoom() is triggered by a button. So every time the button is clicked the **total** value should update.

This code lets the user pick the rooms that they want, and output the result at a **ul** list

```
    <script>
    function standardRoom() {
      var totalStandard = {{$availableRooms[0]['nightRate'] * $n_nights }} * n_standard;

      if ($('select#selectBoxStandard option').length > 1 && Number($("#selectBoxStandard").val()) !== 0) {
        $('#selectBoxStandard').find("option:nth-last-child(-n+" + $('#selectBoxStandard').val() + ")").remove();
            $("#roomDetailStandard ul").html(
            '<li class="pull-right"><h4 style="color:darkorange">PHP ' + totalStandard + '</h4></li>'
          );
          return totalStandard;

      }else {
        alert("Select No. of rooms");
      }
    }

      function quadRoom()
    {
       var totalQuad = {{$availableRooms[1]['nightRate'] * $n_nights}} * n_quad;

      if ($('select#selectBoxQuad option').length > 1 && Number($("#selectBoxQuad").val()) !== 0) {
         $('#selectBoxQuad').find("option:nth-last-child(-n+" + $('#selectBoxQuad').val() + ")").remove();
             $("#roomDetailQuad ul").html(
                '<li class="pull-right"><h4 style="color:darkorange">PHP ' + totalQuad + '</h4></li>'
              );
              return totalQuad;

      }else {
          alert("Select No. of rooms");
      }
    }
</script>
    <div id="roomDetailStandard">
        <ul id="standard">

         </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="roomDetailQuad">
         <ul id="quad">

         </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="totals">
         <ul>
           <li id="total"><h2>Total:</h2> </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
```

The result should be:

> Standard room.
>
> PHP 2000
>
> Quad room
>
> PHP 2500
>
> Total 4500

I tried doing this but it's not working.

```
var standard = standardRoom();
var quad = quadRoom();
var total = standard + quad;
$("#total").html(total)
```

Comment: is it outputting NaN or outputting nothing? also about this line  var totalStandard = {{$availableRooms[0]['nightRate'] * $n_nights }} * n_standard;

Comment: @EmekaOkafor it's outputing nothing. That line is the one that calculate the total of room based on the room type

Comment: if you are trying to output using the {{}} on the script, and the script is saved as script.js, it will not work, the {{}} works only using blade template like myfile.blade.php

Comment: The script is in the blade template, it's not in a separate file

Comment: can i see your controller to see where the problem is

Comment: No, this is just javascript. I don't use any controller for this function

Comment: so where is the value for $availableRooms[0] coming from?

Comment: Oh my bad, you mean that. That is coming from the reservationController but I think i'ts not needed to be included as I was able to output the value of that just fine. So I know that is not the problem here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187803/discussion-between-emeka-okafor-and-rei).

Comment: @EmekaOkafor I'm in the chat room